# Angular 9 use two different layouts in the same application

Tags: javascript, angular, router

My application contains two different layouts. One layout is the application where we show the top navigation and a sidebar.

```
<app-nav></app-nav>
<div>
  <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

and the second layout is the login and signup pages where we don't have the navigation bar and sidebar.

The naive solution will be to add `ngIf` to both elements based on the current route. But I prefer avoiding it. The reason is that we have code inside these components that we don't want to load where we don't need to.

Is there any better solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have the AppComponent contain an `router-outlet` as the template.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Then include routes as:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: AppComponent,
    canActivate: [LanguageGuard]
  },
  {
    path: ':lang',
    component: LanguageComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'partner',
        loadChildren: () => import('./partner/partner.module').then(m => m.PartnerModule)
      },
      ...ClientRoutes,
      ...AuthRoutes
    ]
  }
];
```

My project have different layouts for the `partner` and `ClientRoutes/AuthRoutes`

Partner:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: PartnerLayoutComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'profile',
      component: ProfileComponent
    }
  ]
}];
```

This is the content of ClientRoutes/AuthRoutes:

```
export const ClientRoutes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: ClientLayoutComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'sofa',
      component: SofaComponent
    }
  ]
}];
```

Then you change my `PartnerModule` as your `login` module and lazy load it.

But don't every user need to login? Maybe only put the signup process in that module.

Answer (score 0):

If you're lazy-loading your modules, it's easy:

1. Add a second "layout" page with a `<router-outlet>`
2. In your routes, define your route like this:

   const routes:Routes=[{path:'some-path', component: YourLayoutComponent, loadChildren: ()=> import('./lazy-loaded-module/lazy-loaded.module').then(m=>m.LazyLoadedModule) }];